# For loops with Dask arrays and/or h5py

Tags: python, numpy, dask, h5py

I have a time series with over a hundred million rows of data. I am trying to reshape it to include a time window. My sample data is of shape (79499, 9) and I am trying to reshape it to (79979, 10, 9). The following for loop works fine in numpy.

```
def munge(data, backprop_window):
    result = []
    for index in range(len(data) - backprop_window):
       result.append(data[index: index + backprop_window])
    return np.array(result)

X_train = munge(X_train, backprop_window)
```

I have tried a few variations with dask, but all of them seem to hang without giving any error messages, including this one:

```
import h5py
import dask.array as da
f1 = h5py.File("data.hdf5")
X_train = f1.create_dataset('X_train',data = X_train, dtype='float32') 
x = da.from_array(X_train, chunks=(10000, d.shape[1]))
result = x.compute(munge(x, backprop_window))
```

Any wise thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't necessarily solve your dask issue, but as a much faster alternative to `munge`, you could instead use numpy's `stride_tricks` to create a rolling view into your data (based on example [here](http://arogozhnikov.github.io/2015/09/30/NumpyTipsAndTricks2.html#Rolling-window,--strided-tricks)).

```
def munge_strides(data, backprop_window):
    """ take a rolling view into array by manipulating strides """
    from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
    new_shape = (data.shape[0] - backprop_window,
                 backprop_window,
                 data.shape[1])
    new_strides = (data.strides[0], data.strides[0], data.strides[1])
    return as_strided(data, shape=new_shape, strides=new_strides)

X_train = np.arange(100).reshape(20, 5)

np.array_equal(munge(X_train, backprop_window=3),
               munge_strides(X_train, backprop_window=3))
Out[112]: True
```

`as_strided` needs to be used very carefully - it is an 'advanced' feature and incorrect parameters can easily lead you into segfaults - see [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html)

Comment: Thanks @chrisb. I'll try this when at my desk.